# Text around the SVG

Tags: html, svg

I'm absolutely beginner with SVG, and I need to put text around this moon...
I tried to make text around a path and could not get the right sizes and match it with the moon.

[image]

```html
<svg viewBox="-6 -6 30 40">
    <defs>
        <mask id="earth">
            <rect fill="white" x="-5" y="-5" width="10" height="10"></rect>
            <circle fill="black" cx="3.141592654" r="5" />
        </mask>
    </defs>
    <circle r="5" fill="currentColor" mask="url(#earth)" transform="rotate(-25)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: There's no textPath in your example. So where's the text around a path that you mention in the question.

Comment: @RobertLongson I removed it, I spent 2 hours trying to make another path with a textpath that matches the moon and still failed.
So I dont know how to do it with a textPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw the moon with a path. (and edit in: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/)

The path is drawn counter-clockwise, if you want to draw the innermoon text like your design, it is easier to add a 2nd path drawn clockwise.

Setting `pathLength` helps in positioning with `startoffset`
Look up all attributes you don't know in the docs.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 80 60">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="skyblue"/>
  <path id="Moon" pathLength="10" d="m16 2a12 12 0 1018 13 1 1 0 01-18-13z"/>
  <text>
    <textPath href="#Moon" 
              startoffset="1" text-anchor="left" dominant-baseline="hanging"
              fill="blue" font-size="3px">Outside moon</textPath>
  </text>
  <text>
    <textPath href="#Moon" 
              startoffset="6" text-anchor="right" dominant-baseline="hanging"
              fill="rebeccapurple" font-size="4">Inside moon</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```